# Bash: How to escape $@?

Tags: bash, escaping, command-line-arguments

I need to write a bash script that, among other things, should pass all its arguments intact to another program.

Minimal example:

```
$ cat >proxy.sh 
#!/bin/bash

./script.sh $@
^D

$ chmod +x proxy.sh 

$ cat >script.sh 
#!/bin/bash

echo one $1
echo two $2
echo three $3 
^D

$ chmod +x script.sh
```

This naïve approach does not work for arguments with spaces:

```
$ ./proxy.sh "a b" c
one a
two b
three c
```

Expected:

```
$ ./proxy.sh "a b" c
one a b
two c
three
```

What should I write in `proxy.sh` for this to happen?

Note that I can't use aliases, `proxy.sh` must be a script — it does some stuff before invoking `script.sh`.

Comment: "...should all its arguments intact to another program." -- is that a typo? What did you mean to say?

Comment: "...should *pass* all its arguments..." Fixed, sorry.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Quote `$@`, making it `"$@"`:

```
$ cat >proxy.sh 
#!/bin/bash

./script.sh "$@"
^D
```

Then it retains the original quotes:

```
one a b
two c
three
```

Comment: It works, thanks. I did not expect that, I thought that this would glue all arguments to one... Need to read up on Bash syntax, I guess.

Comment: This is correct. `$@` must always be quoted, or else it doesn't do what you want (it does the same as `$*` instead, which is usually a bug).

Comment: You also have to enclose all other variables in "double quotes" if you want to keep the spaces in them. Except in a few rare cases, so always write `"$var"` instead of `$var`.

Comment: does `ssh -t some-host -C "some-command $@"` quote `$@` as desired?